# Stokes equations in 2D with Neumann conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions, fluid-dynamics

I would like to solve the 2D Stokes equations within a unit disk, say $\Omega$, by using the finite element method (FEM) as it is implemented in `NDSolve` (by loading the finite element package). The examples shown in the FEM documentation only deal with Dirichlet boundary conditions (see [Fluid flow section](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1218020681)). Specifically, I want to numerically find $\boldsymbol{u}=(u,v)$ that solves $-\mu \nabla^2\boldsymbol{u}+\nabla p =0$ and $\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{u}=0$, everywhere within the disk $\Omega$. Here $u$ is the fluid velocity in the $x$ direction and $v$ represents the velocity in the $y$ direction, whist $p$ stands for the pressure in the fluid. On the boundary, $\partial\Omega$, both the normal velocity and the tangential component of the traction are given by$$\left.\boldsymbol{n}\cdot\boldsymbol{u}\right|_{\partial\Omega}=G$$
$$(\mathsf{I}-\boldsymbol{n}\otimes\boldsymbol{n})\left[\boldsymbol{n}\cdot(\mu \nabla\boldsymbol{u}-p\hspace{1pt}\mathsf{I})\right]_{\partial\Omega} = H$$ where $\boldsymbol{n}$ is the unit normal vector and $\mathsf{I}$ is the identity matrix; $G$ and $H$ are prescribed functions.

Here's a starting setup:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Disk[]];
op = {
Inactive[Div][{{-μ, 0}, {0, -μ}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + Derivative[1, 0][p][x, y], 
Inactive[Div][{{-μ, 0}, {0, -μ}}.Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + Derivative[0, 1][p][x, y], 
Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y] + Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y]
} /. {μ -> 1};
NDSolveValue[op=={0,0,0}, {u, v, p}, {x, y} ∈ mesh]]
```

How can one include the above boundary conditions using the `NeumannValue` function on the $u$ and $v$ equations; for instance, the strategy

```
NDSolveValue[op=={NeumannValue[1,True],NeumannValue[1,True],0}, {u, v, p}, {x, y} ∈ mesh]]
```

does not quite work as this only provides the fluxes on $u$ and $v$ (namely, the velocity gradients at the boundary) ignoring the pressure term. Can this even be implemented with the FEM NSolve package?

Edit: Stokes equations are linear, and in the case of a unit disk, as I described the problem above, one could actually solve for this in an analytical form, by using a stream function (that satisfies  $u=\partial\Psi/\partial y$ and $v=-\partial\Psi/\partial x$). However, I'm not particularly interested in such radially symmetric solutions (although this would be useful as a check), since I would like to extend this to a nontrivial boundary, and thus FEM is a must. So, I am wondering whether the FEM package in Mathematica can deal with such traction boundary conditions. Here's a [short lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-HF5-aR_q8) that covers this topic. `NDSolve` seems to be doing the weak formulation internally and leaves very little options to the user.

Comment: Do you have a literature  reference for this, perhaps even an expected solution?

Comment: No, it is impossible to implement mixed boundary conditions in the current version 12.2. In this case we have message `NDSolveValue::fembdcc: Cross-coupling of dependent variables in DirichletCondition[(u x)/Sqrt[x^2+y^2]-(v y)/Sqrt[x^2+y^2]==G[x,y],True] is not supported in this version.`

Comment: @AlexTrounev, the error message you show is for DirichletConditions. I do not think that this is relevant here.

Comment: @user21 Yes you are absolutely right,  `DirichletCondotion[]` is not relevant since  `Cross-coupling of dependent variables in DirichletCondition[] is not supported in this version`. But it can be relevant if somebody from developer will think about it.

Comment: @Alex R Did you take this example from Fenics Project on https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/1.5.0/python/demo/documented/stokes-iterative/python/documentation.html ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I'd approach that. The first thing to realize is that you equation is not in the correct form. You have a non-conservative form of the stokes equation. Your boundary condition, however, suggests that you need a conservative form (You can read up on that in the [MassTransport tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/MassTransport/MassTransport.html)).

Unfortunately, the parser does not handle that in a straight forward manner so we resort to the low level functions (See [finite element programming](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html)).

Set up the numerical region, variables, and solution data:

```
nr = ToNumericalRegion[\[CapitalOmega]];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", 
     "Space"} -> {{u, v, p}, {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {nr}];
```

Set up the method data:

```
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}];
```

Now, comes the key point. The pressure needs to be in conservative form:

```
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd,
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {
      {-mu IdentityMatrix[2], 0, 0},
      {0, -mu IdentityMatrix[2], 0},
      {0, 0, 0}
      } /. mu -> 1,
   "ConservativeConvectionCoefficients" -> {
     {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}},
     {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}},
     {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}
     },
   "ConvectionCoefficients" -> {
     {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
     {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
     {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}
     }
   ];
```

Note, how the pressure is in the conservative convection form, while the divergence of the velocity is in the convection coefficient.

Now, you can use `NeumannValue` to reason about $(\mu \nabla\boldsymbol{u}-p)$ on the boundary. The other thing you are likely going to need is `` NDSolve`FEM`BoundaryUnitNormal `` (Also shown in the mass transport tutorial).

Unfortunately, you did not really provide an example to work on so I can not really show how to set up the BCs. The remainder would then be set up like this:

```
bcdata = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, sd, {
    {},
    {},
    {}
    }];
sdNew = PDESolve[cdata, bcdata, vd, sd, mdata];
{xVel, yVel, pressure} = ProcessPDESolutions[mdata, sdNew]
```

Would be nice to see a result or an updated question.

Comment: Very nice answer! But how we can implement bc with `G=1; H={1,1}`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I think it is better to discuss this with a more concrete example.

Comment: Well, let take $\vec{u}=0, -p \vec {n}+ \frac {\partial \vec {u}}{\partial \vec {n}}=0 $ like in this paper https://mat.fsv.cvut.cz/nales/preprints/preprinty/2009/ulozeneclanky/preprint62009.pdf

Comment: @AlexTrounev, That is `DirichletCondition[{u[x,y]==0,v[x,y]==0}, walls]` and Neumann 0 for the remainder. The BC 1 from the paper is probably not correct. It misses a factor nu.

Comment: And in fact equation 5 has the factor.

Comment: Thank you, it works.

Comment: @user21  interesting how can be implemented  mixed BC for this problem under the low level. For example zero normal velocity and nonzero tangential component of traction vector

Comment: @Alex R Could you please formulate BC in some details. May be it will set in motion the process of finding of solution

Comment: @user21  can we solve coupled pde using staggered scheme in mathematica, can we have a numerical example using staggered scheme in mathematica? thanks in advance!