# Finite-Slip Boundary Conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

### Equations

I am trying to solve the linearized Navier-Stokes equations for a 2D electron fluid given by:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sigma \nabla \Phi + D^2 \nabla^2 \boldsymbol{J}&=\boldsymbol{J} \\
\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{J} &=0,
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\sigma$ is the conductivity, and $D$ is a parameter called the Gurzhi length which is related to the diffusion-length of vorticity in the system (Note that as $D\rightarrow0$, we recover Ohm's law).

First, let's express this in the time-independent coefficients form:

$$
\nabla \cdot \left(-c\nabla \boldsymbol{u} - \alpha \boldsymbol{u} + \gamma \right) + \beta \cdot \nabla \boldsymbol{u} + a \boldsymbol{u} = f,
$$

where we've identified the field and coefficients as:

$\boldsymbol{u}=\begin{pmatrix} \Phi \\ J_x \\ J_y \end{pmatrix}$, $a = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, $c=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & d^2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & d^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, $\beta = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \begin{pmatrix}0 \\0\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}0 \\1\end{pmatrix} \\
 \begin{pmatrix}\sigma \\0\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}0 \\0\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}0 \\0\end{pmatrix} \\
 \begin{pmatrix}0 \\\sigma\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}0 \\0\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}0 \\0\end{pmatrix} \\
\end{array}
\right)$, $\alpha=\gamma=f=0$

and use the PDE building blocks introduced in version 13 for convenience:

```
vars = {ϕ[x, y], Jx[x, y], Jy[x, y]};
reactionTerm = ReactionPDETerm[{vars, {x, y}},
   DiagonalMatrix[{0, 1, 1}]];

diffusionTerm[d_] = DiffusionPDETerm[{vars, {x, y}},
   {{0, 0, 0}, {0, {d^2, d^2}, 0}, {0, 0, {d^2, d^2}}}];

convectionTerm[σ_] = ConvectionPDETerm[{vars, {x, y}},
   {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}},
    {{σ, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
    {{0, σ}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}}];

partialDifferentialEquation[d_, σ_] = reactionTerm + diffusionTerm[d] + convectionTerm[σ]
```

### No-Slip Boundary Conditions

We can solve this using appropriate boundary conditions. E.g. consider [`DirichletCondition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletCondition.html)s for $\Phi$, and the common no-slip boundary conditions for $J_x,J_y$, in a simple channel flow geometry:

```
reg = Rectangle[{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}];
noSlipBCs = {
   DirichletCondition[ϕ[x, y] == 0., x == 1/2],
   DirichletCondition[ϕ[x, y] == 1., x == -1/2],
   DirichletCondition[{Jx[x, y] == 0., Jy[x, y] == 0.}, 
    y == -1/2 || y == 1/2]
   };

parametricSolutions = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
   partialDifferentialEquation[d, 1] == {0, 0, 0},
   noSlipBCs}, {ϕ, Jx, Jy}, {x, y} ∈ reg, {d}, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "InterpolationOrder" -> {ϕ -> 1, Jx -> 2, Jy -> 2}, 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005}}]
```

Varying $D$ and plotting the normalized horizontal current density, we indeed recover something resembling uniform current density as $D\rightarrow 0$, and parabolic current density as $D\rightarrow \infty$:

```
normalizedHorizontalCurrent[d_] := 
 Module[{sol = parametricSolutions[d][[2]], totalCurrent},
  totalCurrent = NIntegrate[sol[0., y], {y, -1/2, 1/2}];
  sol[0., #]/totalCurrent &]

With[{sols = normalizedHorizontalCurrent /@ {0.01, 0.1, 1}},
 Plot[Through[sols[y]] // Evaluate, {y, -1/2, 1/2}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 3/2}, PlotLegends -> {0.01, 0.1, 1}]]
```

[image]

### Finite-Slip Boundary Conditions?

We now wish to impose finite-slip boundary conditions as described in equations (1-3) [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.03933.pdf), given by:

$$
\boldsymbol{J}^t = \zeta \hat{n} \cdot \nabla \boldsymbol{J}^t,
$$

where $\boldsymbol{J}^t= \boldsymbol{J} - \left(\boldsymbol{J}\cdot \hat{n}\right)\hat{n}$ is the tangential current density at the boundary, and $\zeta$ is the slip length. Note that as $\zeta \rightarrow 0$ and $\zeta \rightarrow \infty$ we recover the no-slip and no-stress boundary conditions respectively.

The question is: how do we specify this boundary condition using [`NeumannValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html)? A comment by `user21` in [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/244482) suggests we can use a combination of `Indexed` and `BoundaryUnitNormal` to specify this.

**Note:** I'm aware the simple geometry has both a closed form solution, and that the boundary normals are particularly simple. The actual geometries I want to study do not, hence a general solution in terms of `BoundaryUnitNormal` (or similar) is highly desired.

#### EDIT 01

First, simplify expression using `{nx,ny}`:

```
With[{n = {nx, ny}},
 FullSimplify[
  n .(Grad[{Jx[x, y], Jy[x, y]} - ({Jx[x, y], Jy[x, y]} . n) n, {x,y}])]
 ]
```

> {-((-1+nx^2+ny^2) (nx (Jx^(1,0))[x,y]+ny (Jy^(1,0))[x,y])),-((-1+nx^2+ny^2) (nx (Jx^(0,1))[x,y]+ny (Jy^(0,1))[x,y]))}

And then replace `{nx,ny}` with `BoundaryUnitNormal`:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
neumann = With[{n = BoundaryUnitNormal[x, y]},
  -(n . n - 1) n . Grad[{Jx[x, y], Jy[x, y]}, {x, y}]]

finiteSlipNeumann = {0,
   NeumannValue[Indexed[0.1 neumann, 1], y == -1/2 || y == 1/2],
   NeumannValue[Indexed[0.1 neumann, 2], y == -1/2 || y == 1/2]
   };
```

By removing the `DirichletCondition` on  `Jx` and `Jy`, and adding `finiteSlipNeumann` to the RHS of the equation inside `ParametricNDSolveValue`, but I get this error:

> Derivatives of dependent variables in boundary conditions are not supported with the Finite Element Method in this version of NDSolve.

What is more, the expression I derived above is certainly wrong, since $\hat{n}$ is normalized and thus $\hat{n}\cdot\hat{n}-1$ evaluates to zero.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding your equation setup. If sigma is  conductivity, should this then not go in a diffusive therm (c)? If we assume that the equation is correct (\sigma \nabla \phi), then \sigma needs to be a vector (sigmaX, sigmaY) for it to multiply with gradient phi. Also I do not see terms grad Jx and grad Jy in your equations, yet  you model them.

Comment: Concerning `BoundaryUnitNormal` this represents `{nx, ny}` and with `Indexed` you can extract a part of that vector, if needed.

Comment: Thanks @user21 - The equation is correct (and indeed \sigma here is isotropic), although I forgot to specify the continuity equation (essentially J acts as an incompressible fluid). See edit. Re: the `NeumannValue` - I'm not sure I expressed it correctly, since I'm getting an error about derivatives of dependent variables..

Comment: In-fact, pde error aside - the expression I used is certainly wrong since the normals are normalized and thus `{nx,ny}.{nx,ny}-1` evaluates to zero

Comment: Currently (V13.0), you can not use the derivative of the dependent variable in NeumannValue. But this came up the third time now the past week. Seems relevant to have....